# WIA: device.ExecuteCommand(CommandID.wiaCommandTakePicture); returns null

Tags: c#, windows-7, wia

Have an old program I have been using to remotely control a digital camera, in order to automatically take photos and transfer them to the PC. Program is based on WIA and, as far as I remember, it was originally designed and used on Windows XP.

Recently took it out of the archives, and have been trying to get it to work on 64-bit Windows 7 using the same camera. Locating the camera, and triggering a capture works without issue. However when executing this line:

```
//device of type WIA.Device
Item item = device.ExecuteCommand(CommandID.wiaCommandTakePicture);
```

null is returned, leaving me without an image reference to transfer. Have been searching high and low for a solution, but have been unable to come up with anything. Found another QA site where an answer suggested that using:

```
//manager of type WIA.DeviceManager, device of type WIA.Device
manager.RegisterEvent(EventID.wiaEventItemCreated, device.DeviceID);
manager.OnEvent += new _IDeviceManagerEvents_OnEventEventHandler(manager_OnEvent);
```

one would receive events containing an itemID after image capture. Have tried this, and no event gets raised.

Comment: Was unable to find a solution, so I choose to install XP Mode for Windows 7 and run the program in the VM.

Comment: hi do you have the sample of your code, where you call the Device Manger dialog.. I am using something like this WIA.CommonDialog dlg = new WIA.CommonDialog(); and this is not working in XP but it works fine in Win 7. I have to do the same (taking pictures and saving it in disk on an XP machine.)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, WIA has **many** oddities.  I also struggled with the `null` returned by `Item item = device.ExecuteCommand(CommandID.wiaCommandTakePicture);` and though I am developing in Windows 7, my machine is 32-bit.

The solution, on my machine, is listening for the event as mentioned in the original question.  If that's not working, try registering for the event using the wildcard device id:

```
manager.RegisterEvent(EventID.wiaEventItemCreated, Miscellaneous.wiaAnyDeviceID);
device.ExecuteCommand(CommandID.wiaCommandTakePicture);
```

I also found that I needed to re-register the event after each device command, otherwise it would stop triggering.